# Symfony2 Translate Assertion message from entity annotation

Tags: symfony

I have an entity with some validation and assertion messages.
I need to translate that messages into arabic
i have a messages.ar.xlf file
The validation message from the Entity is not translated!

```
    <trans-unit id="1">
        <source>Enter.Car.Details</source>
        <target>بيانات السيارة</target>
    </trans-unit>
```

and here's my Entity

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\Length(max = "4", maxMessage = "Enter.Car.Details")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Enter.Car.Details")
 * @ORM\Column(name="year_made", type="integer", length=4, nullable=true)
 */
private $yearMade;
```

and here's my config.yml

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: ar }
```

Note :- I translated some words in my twig file to check if the local and messages.ar.xlf file are working or not, and it's all working except the validation messages coming from the Entity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The validation messages are get not from `messages` domain, but from `validators` one.

So create `validators.ar.xlf` file and put your validation messages there and should be working (see the [official Symfony2 documentation for reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translating-constraint-messages)).

One more thing. Depending on what Symfony version do you use: `maxLength` assertion id deprecated from Symfony 2.1 and is removed in 2.3. So, if you use Symfony >2.0, then you should use `Length` assertion instead.

Comment: Yeaaaaaaaaaaaah, thank you :) i should use validators.ar.xlf not messages.ar.xlf